# In Maven is there a way to replace properties in the POM file itself like Ant's build.properties file?

Tags: maven, properties, pom.xml

I'm not talking about the Maven Properties Plugin, or resource filtering. I want Maven to replace properties in the POM itself. For example, let's say I have several POMs that reference a particular dependency's version number. I want to be able to load in one properties file for each of those POMs, and then change the values once. Maven would then read the properties file before processing the POM and replace accordingly. I believe this is how Ant does it in a single pass, and the properties are then immutable within the build.xml.

Comment: What is wrong with the properties plugin? That's what it does.

Comment: @DaveNewton Take a parent and a child POM. Give the parent POM a version number, and now in the child POM in the <parent><version> node, use ${parent.project.version}. It will throw an error. The issue is that before a child POM can reference parent POM properties it must first have a version for that parent. I don't want to deal with this relationship dependency. All properties need to instead be "pre-processed".

Answer (score 1):

You can do property replacement on the command line if that fits your situation.  I change the version of my project in the pom on the commandline (really through NAnt scripts).  For example:

```
mvn deploy -Dproject.version=1.00.00.0-Something-SNAPSHOT
```

You mentioned you want to change a property that is within the parent tags.  In maven 2 (not sure about maven 3) anything within the parent tags cannot be a property and must be the actual values.  Maven doesn't evaluate properties with in the parent tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a multi-module build which often comes to the point of the version number. But the simple answer for that is: Use the maven release plugin so you don't need to deal with the version numbers. Or you can use the versions-maven-plugin to handle modifications of them in an elegant way. And it's best practive not to use properties for versions of parents in pom's (onr that it will work as you described).